# How to create new column for comma separated values in CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create new column for comma separated values in CSV file. Here I'm using PHP CodeIgniter frame work. In below I have mentioned my student controller:

```
public function export_stdinfo() {
        $filename = 'std_info.csv';
        $path = 'folder_path';
        
        if (!file_exists($path)){
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }
        
        $activity_data = [];
        $stdinfo = $this->Std_Model->get_stdinfo();
        $output = fopen($path.$filename, 'w');
        
        fputcsv($output, array('Std.rollno','Std.class','Std_name','Activities'));
        
        foreach ($stdinfo as $key=> $line) {
            $activity_data = explode(",", $line['Activities']);
            
            fputcsv($output,$line);
        }
        
        fclose($output);
    $file_url = $path.$filename;
        
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
        readfile($file_url);
    exit;
    }
```

In above my code everything is working fine in CSV file generating side. But in my activity column I have comma separated values. This activity data needs to be added to new columns while generating CSV file.

After exporting CSV file result file will show as like this

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGxyd.png)

But I want to print out file like this

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETmyA.png)

Actually, I'm trying to add new column for activity data using explode function but it's not working. I don't know how to merge this data to fputcsv. please help me out.

Comment: CSV is not a flexible format, either _all_ the fields exist in _all_ the row, or your document is corrupted. You need to know the maximum number of "activity" columns in the document, and then you need to generate _all_ rows with that number, blank or not. You cannot both append to the file and change the number of columns, you would have to re-generate the file entirely.

Comment: However, the larger problem is that your data is not normalized to the extent that would make it fit properly in a tabular store. If you were to make the rows repeat for each activity or otherwise split the data off into a separate document, it would be more manageable the same way as you would for normalizing a database schema.

Comment: `$activity_data = explode(",", $line['Activities']); unset($line['Activities']); $line += $activity_data;` - you'll lose the `Activities` _key_ that way, the individual activities will be added under new, numeric keys; but for writing the line, that should not matter. And of course this can only make sense, if that `Activities` column is the last column of your input data.

Comment: @CBroe , Thanks a lot it's working fine now. but I have small thing here, If I have another column with comma separated values means, could I do that same logic for another column or  what exactly ?

Comment: In theory, yes, but you'd be really very likely to run into problems then, when you don't have the same number of values across all rows. And if you wanted to fill in "empty" columns for rows that have less, you would have to determine the maximum number of values beforehand.